# Compilation problem in tokyo cabinate C program

Tags: c, tokyo-cabinet

i am new to tokyo cabinet and i have installed it and i have run the example c program i am getting error...
while i compile with gcc

```
gcc -O tcadbex.c 

/tmp/cc7IEOht.o: In function `main':
tcadbex.c:(.text+0xd): undefined reference to `tcadbnew'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `tcadbopen'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `tcadbput2'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x74): undefined reference to `tcadbput2'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x90): undefined reference to `tcadbput2'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `tcadbget2'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `tcadbiterinit'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x11c): undefined reference to `tcadbget2'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `tcadbiternext2'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x164): undefined reference to `tcadbclose'
tcadbex.c:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `tcadbdel'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

can any one tell me what is the issues with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will almost certainly have to link with the library files for Tokyo Cabinate (whatever that is).

Typically, you would use a command like:

```
gcc -o tcadbex -L/usr/lib -lxyz tcadbex.c
```

where:

- `-L` specifies search paths for libraries.
- `-l` lists libraries to search for undefined symbols.

and the linker will go looking for the libraries, following certain rules for turning `xyz` into a file name like `libxyz.so`.

In fact, a search of the net turns up [this](http://fallabs.com/tokyocabinet/spex-en.html) (on one line, I'm just splitting it for readability):

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include tc_example.c -o tc_example
    -L/usr/local/lib -ltokyocabinet -lz -lbz2 -lrt -lpthread -lm -lc
```

as the command line to use.

so I would suggest that you need for your specific case (again, on one line):

```
gcc -I/usr/local/include tcadbex.c -o tcadbex
    -L/usr/local/lib -ltokyocabinet -lz -lbz2 -lrt -lpthread -lm -lc
```

Comment: i get this  if i run the above cmd ..but my java api works fine,,, but i need it in c
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcadb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @raj, check the update, the library has a different name to the one I used as an example.